# Regex for hex value not working in python

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, hex

I am trying to find and replace special characters like "vertical tab" and "non-breaking space" in python.

Sample string:
`input = 'This is an interesting\x0b test'`

When I use `re.sub('[\x0b]', ' ', input)`, it does match as expected but why does not `re.sub('[\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}]', ' ', input)` work? I want to match other special characters too!

Some background: These special characters are passed to my python handler from the search url as `q=This%20is%20an%20interesting%0B%20test` (notice `%OB`, this is the vertical tab character) and get read in python as `\x0b`. If I do not handle this, it fails and results in the following error in the Google Appengine search api
`raise QueryError('Failed to parse query "%s"' % query)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first regex is not matching how you think it is.

The regex `[\x0b]` matches *the single character* which is the ASCII byte 11 (0x0B in hex) - it is in fact equivalent to the same regex without brackets, since a character class with one character is redundant: `\x0b`.

Trying to use a bracket expression for the `0b` portion doesn't work because `\x0b` is an atomic representation of a single character, not something that you can use regex representation within.

What you may want to do is instead match any character you *don't* want to allow in search queries for replacement, e.g.:

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', ' ', input)
```

Note the `^` at the beginning of the bracketed character class, which means the character class is inverted - it will match anything that *isn't* explicitly specified.

Comment: I like your suggestion to restrict the input to alphanumeric characters but disagree with your opinion on how _[\x0b] matches any single character_. I did the following test to check that and it suggests that `[\x0b]` is taken as a single hex entity instead of individual characters.

`>>> input = 'This is an interesting\x0b test best \ x 0'
>>> re.sub('[\x0b]', ' ', input)
'This is an interesting  test best \\ x 0'
>>> re.sub(r'\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}', ' ', input)
'This is an interesting\x0b test best \\ x 0'
>>> re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', ' ', input)
'This is an interesting  test best   x 0'`

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the form of your data. I've revised the answer in light of that.

Comment: Thanks. So I understand this as a limitation in regex. Thanks again for the alternative approach though.

Comment: It's not a limitation in regex - if your `[\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}]` did what you wanted it to, it would actually match *any character*, not just special characters - for instance, `'a'` is `'\x61'`.

Comment: Aah, I see. I just tested it too and it indeed works the way you pointed out. Thanks!